# executing a command in shell

Tags: bash, shell

My directory structure:

```
root\bin\run.sh \\main shell file i am trying to write
root\folder1\script.py  
root\folder2\script2.py

So, I want to execute run.sh (from anywhere).. and then first execute

 python root\folder1\script.py
 python root\folder2/script2.py
```

But, I don't want to give the full path.. as that might change (depending on which system, I am running the code...) but the relative paths between run.sh script.py and script2.py will not change..
So, how do i do this in shell?

Comment: In addition to the many, many duplicate StackOverflow questions, this is also BashFAQ #28: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Comment: First: Use forward slashes.